# Retrieving count with leading zeros

Tags: xslt

I am retrieving to fetch the count of rows which I gor from SQL Server using a column. I am achieving it through

xsl:value-of select='format-number(count(//Report/ABC_Data/Details_Collection/Details/Sequence_Number),"#")'

But the issue is, I need it for 6 characters & if the count is just 2 digits, say 62, I need it as 000062. Any help on this please ?

Also is there a way to add two nodes (And pad it with leading zero's : length is 20)?

I am trying as

xsl:value-of select='format-number(sum(//Report/ABC_Data/Details_Collection/Details/Initial_Amount|Final_Amount),"$#.00")'>

Comment: The XPath tag is probably more appropriate here than XSLT :)

Answer (score 0):

Your number pattern needs to look like `000000` rather than using # characters:

```
format-number(62, '000000')
```

gives `000062`.

You can use a node-set in sum: try something like:

```
sum((//Report/ABC_Data/Details_Collection/Details/Initial_Amount, //Report/ABC_Data/Details_Collection/Details/Final_Amount))
```

The outer set of brackets is for the sum function; the inner set is to define a (comma separated) node set sequence.  Note that each XPath term could theoretically return a sequence of more than one value!

Comment: <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(//Report/ABC/Details_Collection/Details/Initial_amt,//Report/ABC_Data/Details_Collection/Details/final_amt),'#.00')"></xsl:value-of>
Tried adding my code like this. Throwing an error : 
Function 'sum()' must have 1 argument(s).

Comment: Yes: as explained above, the double parentheses are important!